# Date -time observations

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, timestamp

I have data in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format i.e. 2015-02-13 07:30:12, 2015-02-13 18:30:12 and 2015-02-13 19:30:12, and so on. Each data point represents one onservations. I am interested to calculate the hourly observations i.e. from 2015-02-13 04:25:00 to 2015:02:13 17:25:00.
A sample data set is attached here as well.

Comment: It's not really clear what exactly you're looking for or the relationship between data1 and data2 -- you get nothing from the names. Could you clarify,  please?

Comment: I am looking for the hourly number (before and after) of observations in data2 with respect to data1. For example, 2015-2-13T19:30:12 is the first observation in data1, I want to calculate the number of events in data2 with 2 hours after/before this value 2015-2-13T19:30:12.

Comment: Let me suggest again you reword you question. Here's why: There is no way to understand the relationship between the two sets. It looks like you are wanting to know 10x the data points (+/- 2, 6, 12, 24 & 72 hrs) that would be 1640. **BUT** what you have  `2015-02-13T17:30:12`, `2015-02-13T18:30:12` and `015-02-13T19:30:12`, `13T20:30:12` -- which are one hour increments *and not even formated correctly*. So, basically, it's like you're saying "figure out my datasets, figure out my problem and figure out my code"

Comment: Apology for the unclear question. Let me try again to make my question more understandable. Suppose we have data like  2015-2-15 19:30:12, 2015-2-16 23:38:28, 2015-2-17 0:33:31these three data/time values represent 3 events. I am interested to calculate the hourly events say 5 before and after 2015-02-16 10:45:00. So, we need to calculate hourly events from 2015-02-16 05:45:00 (5 hours before) and 2015-02-16 15:45:00 (5 hours after). Hope so this makes my problem relatively clear.

Comment: Is there a column of data going along with this?  Otherwise, what is it that you are counting per hour?

Comment: yes, but each date-time value represents an observation. So I just used the only date-time value

Comment: Rewording the question was helpful (and quite a bit different than what I thought you were originally asking) but I think we need the data here to show proof of work. If I have what you're saying correct, you just need the number of the events that occur within a timespan.

Comment: Exactly, I just need the number of events occurred in that particularly time on an hourly basis.